# Portmanteau Theorem in Billingsley's Book

Tags: probability-theory

In Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures, he states the following Portmanteau Theorem and gives a proof.

> **Theorem 2.1** These five conditions are equivalent:
> (i) $P_n\Rightarrow P$.
> (ii) $P_nf\rightarrow Pf$ for all bounded, uniformly continuous $f$.
> (iii) $\limsup_nP_nF\leq PF$ for all closed F.
> (iv) $liminf_nP_nG\geq PG$ for all open $G$.
> (v) $P_nA\rightarrow PA$ for all $P-continuity$ sets A.

> **Proof of $(v)\rightarrow(i)$** By linearity we may assume that the bounded $f$ satisfies  $0<f<1$. Then $Pf=\int_0^\infty P[f>t]dt=\int_0^\infty P[f>t]dt$, and similarly for $P_nf$. If $f$ is continuous, then $\partial [f>t]\subset [f=t]$, and hence $[f>t]$ is a P-continuity set except for countably many $t$. By condition (v) and the bounded convergence theorem, $P_nf=\int_0^1 P_n[f>t]dt \rightarrow \int_0^1 P[f>t]dt =Pf.$

What puzzles me is the second sentence of the proof. Yes, when $f$ is continuous, $\partial [f>t]\subset [f=t]$ should hold. But why hence $[f>t]$ is a P-continuity set except for countably many $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{f=t\}, 0 <t <\infty$ is a disjoint collection of measurable sets. Since $P$ is a probability measure at most countbaly many of these sets can have positive measure.

[There can be at most $N$ values of $t$ for which $P(f=t) >\frac  1N$ since $P(\Omega)=1$. Now take the union over all $N$].